# how to share user authenticate login data between http and www

Tags: php, yii

i am using Yii framework when users open the site `www.dominname.com`
and log-in to the site, the authenticate or user sessions data are not the same on 
`http://dominname.com` 
so users have to log-in again when they open HTTP how, can i make the authenticate log-in are done on the WWW and HTTP or share the sessions data between WWW and HTTP.
is there is any config for Yii to solve this issue ?

---

This code working for me if user check the `rememberMe` else user will not be logged-in
Does anyone know how to solve this?

1. main /config

   ```
     'user' => array(
       // enable cookie-based authentication
       'class' => 'WebUser',
       'allowAutoLogin' => true,
   ),
   'session' => array(
   'savePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '../../session',
   'cookieMode' => 'allow',
       'cookieParams' => array(
           'path' => '/',
           'domain' => '.domainname.org',
           'httpOnly' => true,
       ),
   ),
   ```
2. components / WebUser

   ```
   class WebUser extends CWebUser {

     public $identityCookie = array(
    'path' => '/',
    'domain' => '.domainname.org',
     );
    public function init() {
    $conf = Yii::app()->session->cookieParams;
    $this->identityCookie = array(
       'path' => $conf['path'],
       'domain' => $conf['domain'],
    );
    parent::init();
    }
     public function logout($destroySession = true) {
     if ($this->allowAutoLogin && isset($this->identityCookie['domain'])) {
        $cookies = Yii::app()->getRequest()->getCookies();
         if (null !== ($cookie = $cookies[$this->getStateKeyPrefix()])) {
            $originalCookie = new CHttpCookie($cookie->name, $cookie->value);
             $cookie->domain = $this->identityCookie['domain'];
            $cookies->remove($this->getStateKeyPrefix());
            $cookies->add($originalCookie->name, $originalCookie);
            }
      }
     parent::logout($destroySession);
     }
    }
   ```

Comment: Thank you that was really helpful but still have a problem with log-in if user doesn't check the remember me in the log-in form please check my code above and thank you again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Except when there is a reason to have separate www and non-www domains, it's better to redirect the www of non-www domain to the other. Also, it's better for SEO. You can do this by adding this to your .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
rewritecond %{http_host} ^yoursite.com
rewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```